# Create a multiple criteria, multiple row 'IF and MIN' conditional formula

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have a spreadsheet with values from a drainage program (pipes and pits) and I want to create a formula that will find the Pit name and then find the minimum value in the downstream end of the pipe that connects to that pit.

That I can do with an array - `{=MIN(IF('ArcGIS Pipes'!$C$2:$C$100=A3,'ArcGIS Pipes'!$F$2:$F$100))}`. However, sometimes the pit only connects to the upstream end which means it's in a different column under `U/S IL (m)`. If that's the case then I want that value, but at the moment I'm having to first run the `D/S IL (m)` column formula, if that returns nothing then I have to manually change the `null` cells to `{=MIN(IF('ArcGIS Pipes'!$B$2:$B$100=A2,'ArcGIS Pipes'!$E$2:$E$100))}` which checks the `U/S IL (m)` column. Once I've done that any leftover `null` values are pits which don't connect to any pipes and they're manually given a null value.

So, what I want to do is have the one formula that does all of the above for me without me having to go through and fiddle things. In short I want the formula to first check for a minumum downstream value in one column, if that returns nothing then I want it to check for the minimum upstream value in another column, finally if that returns nothing then I want a null value returned.

I've fiddled around with nested IFs and sub arrays but just get an error or a  `FALSE` returned. The formula I've tried that gives me `FALSE` is `=IF((MIN(IF('ArcGIS Pipes'!$C$2:$C$100=A2,'ArcGIS Pipes'!$F$2:$F$100))),IF(MIN(IF('ArcGIS Pipes'!$B$2:$B$100=A2,'ArcGIS Pipes'!$E$2:$E$100)),null))`. I know I'm missing something but I'm starting to go around in circles!

[Screengrab - left table is the source table, right is the results table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlnQr.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the table?

Comment: Please format the formulas; they are currently a nightmare to read.

Comment: If I understand, why not try `=If([first formula]=0,[second formula],[first formula])`? You should check the result of running it in the first column. If that's `0` when it's in the second column, then run the second formula.

Comment: That's almost there, thankyou @BruceWayne! The only thing missing is how to turn the resultant 0 value when nothing is found into a randomly assigned null' such as -999.

Comment: Sorry read this wrong, Without stealing @BruceWayne's answer, add a further if() so it looks like this : =If([first formula]=0,[second formula],if([second formula]=0,"-999",[second formula]).

Answer (score 1):

This may be the array formula¹ that you are looking for. In K2 as,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(H2,C:C, 0)),
      AGGREGATE(15, 6, F$2:INDEX(F:F, MATCH("zzz",C:C ))/(C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH("zzz",C:C ))=H2), 1),
   IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(H2,B:B, 0)),
      AGGREGATE(15, 6, E$2:INDEX(E:E, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))/(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("zzz",B:B ))=H2), 1),
      "no match"))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>